# How to determine the type of the object an iterator is pointing to in c++ template function?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, c++14

I have a template function in C++ that serializes an iterable:

```
template<typename Stream, typename Iter, typename Infix, typename Closure>
inline Stream &stream_iterable(Stream &os, Iter from, Iter to, Infix infix_, Closure open, Closure close) {
    if (from == to) return os;
    os << open << *from;
    for (++from; from != to; ++from) {
        os << infix_ << *from;
    }
    os << close;
    return os;
}
```

For examaple, it basically converts `std::vector<int>{1,2}` to a string `"[1,2]"`

I would like to check the type of the object the iterator is pointing to and if it is `std::string`, I would like to use `std::quoted` to add quotation around the elements of the vector, Something like this:

```
template<typename Stream, typename Iter, typename Infix, typename Closure>
inline Stream &steam_iterable_quoted(Stream &os, Iter from, Iter to, Infix infix_, Closure open, Closure close) {
    if (from == to) return os;
    os << open << std::quoted(*from);
    for (++from; from != to; ++from) {
        os << infix_ << std::quoted(*from);
    }
    os << close;
    return os;
}
```

How can I check the type of (*from) and combine these two functions into one?

Comment: I suggest using *specialization* instead of "checking" type.

Comment: Are you compiling with C++17?

Comment: I am compiling with C++ 14

Comment: @motam79: Then specialization is your answer. in C++17 we can use `if constexpr` to perform compile-time type checking (& branching) in a more readable manner.

Comment: @AndyG I agree, after reading about if constexpr. I am motivated to upgrade to C++17. It makes the template code much more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simplest, working version:

```
namespace quoting {
  template<class T>
  T const& auto_quote( T const& t ) { return t; }
  template<class C, class T>
  auto auto_quote( std::basic_string<C,T> const& s ) {
    return std::quoted(s);
  }
  // add more std types that need quoting here.
}
```

now do this:

```
// ...
if (from == to) return os;
using quoting::auto_quote;
os << open << auto_quote(*from);
for (++from; from != to; ++from) {
    os << infix_ << auto_quote(*from);
}
os << close;
// ...
```

in order to make something be quoted differently, override `auto_quote` in the namespace of the type (if not in `std`; no injecting names into `std` allowed) or in `namespace quoting`.  It will be picked up automatically.

So if you have your `my_string` in namespace `my_ns`:

```
namespace my_ns {
  auto auto_quote( my_string const& s ) {
    // some manual quoting code
  }
}
```

and it will be picked up automatically by the above code.

Comment: It works. Thanks! Just a question: why do we need two template types: template<class C, class T> for the string case?

Comment: @motam79 because the standard?  One is the char, the other the traits.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need to know the type in the body of `stream_iterable`. As the old saying goes, add a level of indirection:

```
namespace detail {
  template<typename T>
  constexpr T const& prepare_to_print(T const& t) { return t; }

  auto prepare_to_print(std::string const s&) { return std::quoted(s); }
  // A non-const overload would be required as well...
  // Forwarding can be a drag sometimes 
}
```

Just pass the dereferenced iterator to `prepare_to_print`. The nice thing about overloads is that you can customize the behavior further by adding more of them later on.

Comment: Care with forward reference against regular overloads: `std::string&` would take forwarding one :/.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Yeah, I omitted a fair few overloads for simplicity. Though if you ask me that's a language defect, plain and simple :S. At least in this case the default behavior is to do nothing.

Comment: `const T&` would be enough in that case. (we don't consume/mutate parameter for printing normally).

Comment: @Jarod42 - Mmm.. Yeah I suppose code would have to be truly Machiavellian to break with a mere `const&` overload

Answer (score 0):

You can use `decltype(*from)` to obtain the result type of the dereference operator, but (1) it may need to be further massaged before doing comparisons (it may be a reference, a value, possibly cv-qualified, ...), and (2) it's not really extensible WRT other types.

In general for this kind of stuff you want to delegate to a template function that (in your case) is responsible to actually output the datum on the stream, with a default for the "normal" types, and specialize it for types that require special treatment.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to retrieve type of object referenced by an iterator: `std::iterator_triats<SomeIteratorType>::value_type`

To combine these two functions you can use constexpr if statement which is a C++17 feature.